# Responsive Grid Breaking when viewed on mobile device in landscape format

Tags: css, ios, grid, responsive-design

I'm building a website using Andy Taylor's '[1140px Grid System](http://cssgrid.net/)'.

All is fine in an Android browser, but on an iPhone 3g in Safari when you rotate into landscape view, the content of the grid flows out of the viewport. See the image below...

[image: iPhone Screenshots]

Comment: Please note that you can answer your own question.

Comment: Have edited the original question.

Comment: You should have an "Answer Your Question" button. Not sure if you need a minimum rep for that :-?

Comment: Yup, have to wait 8 hours for that :-/

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to this question:

Originally in the header we had this to set the viewport scale:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

However, my colleague discovered that for iOS devices you need to use the following instead which sets a minimum and maximum scale for iOS viewports:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"  />
```

You can read some information about this issue on the [HTML5 Boilerplate's Github repository](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/37)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem myself and went googling. The solution above is mentioned in many blogs and articles, but considered a "cure that kills the patient" because it disables user scaling (pinch/zoom) in iOS4 ans iOS5.

There seems to be a better solution developed by the Filament Group, which only disables user scaling temporarily until the orientation change to landscape has taken place.

[Controlling text size in Safari for iOS without disabling user zoom](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/)

[A Fix for the iOS Orientationchange Zoom Bug](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/a_fix_for_the_ios_orientationchange_zoom_bug/)

I hope this helps.